# Disable months included in references when using APACITE

Tags: citing

I'm using APACITE for my project, but in the bibliography the references doesn't look quite right!

Here's an example:

```
Agrawal, R., Imielinski, T. & Swami, A. (1993, 6). Mining association rules between sets
of items in large databases. SIGMOD Rec., 22 (2), 207-216. Retrieved from http://
doi.acm.org/10.1145/170036.170072
```

This doesn't look quite right to me? The "6"(month) shouldn't be after the date, should it?

Answer (score 2):

Just delete the label 'month' in the bib reference, and the month will not show up

The month should show up as 'June' in your example though. See the following example.

```
@MISC{w3c:2014:tpe,
  title = {Tracking {P}reference {E}xpression {(DNT)}.},
  howpublished={{W3C Last Call Working Draft}.},
  author={Fielding, {R. T.} and Singer, David},
    month=apr # "~24",
    year = {2014},
  url={http://www.w3.org/TR/tracking-dnt/ },
    urldate={2 May 2014},
}
```

This results in:

```
Fielding, R., & Singer, D. (2014, April 24). Tracking Preference
Expression (DNT). W3C Last Call Working Draft.  Retrieved 2 May 2014,
from http://www.w3.org/TR/tracking-dnt/
```

Due to the way Bibtex works out the day and month, it needs a string for the day(s). e.g., multiple days would be;

```
month=apr # "~28-29",
```

Comment: Why doesnt it show as june ?Do I actually have to write june instead of "6" in the .bib file?

Comment: Still, I want a sollution which makes the apacite package ignore the month.

Comment: Just delete the label 'month' in the bib reference, and the month will not show up.

Comment: That takes ages, you have to delete the month field for all the references.

Comment: I use a macro in notepad++. You can also use sed via commandline. sed '/pattern to match/d' ./file.bib > filenew.bib

Comment: sed '/month.*/d' ./file.bib > filenew.bib

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23088/discussion-between-rvaneijk-and-minihessel).

Comment: Why do you use *month=apr # "~24"*?  Why not use *month=apr, day=24*?

Comment: This is due to the way Bibtex works out the day and month. It needs a string for the day(s). e.g., multiple days would be; #"~24-26".

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to remove the month field from each of the entries in the bib file, as suggested in the comments here

Comment: Well deleting information only to avoid that it shows up in some cases is at best a hack. It would be better to change the bst so that it doesn't include the month - or better to switch to biblatex (biblatex-apa)  and biber  where you can remove fields on the fly.